# Rspec: Test if instance method was called on specific record with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm looking to write a controller spec which tests if a method was called on an instance of a model class for ActiveRecord.

For example, there is a model `Post` and I want to check if the post with the id 55 had the method `foobar` called on it.

Some ways that almost work:

- `expect_any_instance_of(Post).to receive(:foobar)`

This almost works but it can not check which post the method was called on

- using `double`

This would normally work but in the controller spec, only ids are passed over so I have no way of inserting the double, short of mocking the response from activerecord `find`

Does rspec provide any tools to check a method was called on a specific model instance?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can do expect(Post).to receive(:find).with(id: your_instance_id) this kinda makes sure your instance will be fetched from the db.

Comment: Mocking the Post find method call should solve the issue-
`allow(Post).to receive(:find).and_return(your_mocked_post_object)`

Comment: The use of controller specs/tests is discouraged by both the Rails and RSpec teams. You want to use [request specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec). You also seem to be focusing far to much on testing the implementation - "tests if a method was called on an instance of a model class" instead of testing the actual behavior - eg what is supposed to happen when the method is called.

Comment: I wonder if you can test the side effects of the method - for example does it update the database? If you want to stub the method because it touches an application boundry (like for example it does a HTTP call) you should consider creating a separate object (a client or service object) which you can stub and set expectations on.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but requires much more mocking, and this means that you're testing the implementation details of a controller which is an antipattern.

Assuming your controller is this:

```
def action(id)
  Post.find(params[:id]).foobar
end
```

You'd need to mock sth like this (I'll ignore RSpec's good practices like having vars in let's, you can easily extract it later when you have a working example):

```
mock = instance_double(Post)
expect(Post).to receive(:find).with(55).and_return(mock)
expect(mock).to receive(:foobar)

# trigger the action here
```

But as the comments already stated, it's probably cleaner to test side effects. If your action deletes a Post, check that the post has been deleted

```
expect { trigger_action params: {id: 55} }.to change(Post, :count).by(-1)
```

This makes your code less brittle (you can refactor the internals, and the specs for the controller stay green - meaning your app still works as described in those specs).