# Rspec expect to receive not working for object in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm sure this is answered somewhere; I can't seem to phrase my google search right though. I'm trying to test that a method is called on an object, but the method isn't called on the specific object in the spec. The method is called on the last item in a collection, which I've confirmed is the same underlying object as the one in the spec. I'm not sure how clear that was, so here is an example:

```
expect(@email).to receive(:send) # fails
puts @user.emails.last == @email # true
@user.emails.last.send
```

As a sanity check, this spec passes. However the code I'm testing has `@user.emails.last.send` in it, so I'm trying to figure out how to make the spec above pass.

```
expect(@email).to receive(:send) # passes
@email.send
```

Edit:

`@user.emails.last.equal?(@email)` returns false, so as suspected by [@spickermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2483313/spickermann)
 and [@Grzegorz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299774/grzegorz) the `@user.emails.last` and `@email` are two instances of the same object. So I guess what I'm asking is how can I test that the `send` method was called on a specific object (ignoring what particular instance of that object it was called on). My question is actually the same as this one that I just found [Rspec: Test if instance method was called on specific record with ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67156441/rspec-test-if-instance-method-was-called-on-specific-record-with-activerecord).

Comment: How do you initialize `@email` and `@user`? Are `@user.emails.last` and `@email` really the exact same instance of an email or are they two different instances of the same email?

Comment: What does `@user.emails.last.equal?(@email)` return?

Comment: After reading last edit: There are at least 2 ways to achieve it. 1. is described in my answer (last code example `expect(@user.emails.last).to receive(:send)`). 2nd is to control the way `user` object sets it's `emails` objects. You can ready dependency injection, and inversion of control to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that `==` method is defined on the mail object in a way that it returns true if some attributes are the same, but it doesn't care if the object is the same.

```
@user.emails.last == @email
```

This is the case with a simple string:

```
>> "d" == "d"
=> true
>> "d".object_id == "d".object_id
=> false
```

So It is possible that `@mail` and `@user.emails.last` are different objects in memory, but return true when using `==` method.

You can confirm that there's nothing wrong with your expectation like this:

```
expect(@user.emails.last).to receive(:send) # should pass now
@user.emails.last.send
```

You didn't share much code for context, so it's not clear what a "good" solution in your case could be. But I hope this will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm able to work around this by returning the Email instance (`@user.emails.last`) from the `send_email` method and ensuring that is the same object as the `@email` object in the spec. E.g.,:

```
# The `send_email` method calls `@user.emails.last.send` and returns `@user.emails.last`
email = @user.send_email
expect(email).to eq(@email) # passes!
```

Comment: I'm glad you managed to overcome the obstacle, please be aware that having production code decisions driven by the need of the tests is a code smell. You also dealt with a manifestation of the problem (workaround) instead of the root cause issue. So If you don't mind me sharing some life experience: I leveled up as a dev when I started to do less of the former and pushed myself to do more of the latter.